# Why my touchpad does not work properly?

Tags: asus-laptop, synaptics-touchpad

The touch-pad of my ASUS laptop does not work properly.The synaptic properties of touch-pad are disabled! The tab "device setting" does not appear on the mouse properties window. Please help me to fix it!
In more detail, the touch-pad is working properly for simple operations. However special synaptic services  which work by two fingers stopped working anymore. My laptop has a touch screen.

Comment: Have you installed the drivers for your synaptic device?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the way it doesn't work properly?

Comment: More detail are added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Search for your laptop model [on ASUS's site](http://support.asus.com/download/options.aspx?SLanguage=en&type=1) and download the related touchpad drivers. You either didn't install the drivers or deleted them. Just download and install the drivers from ASUS website. It should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is impossible to partially delete the driver. Touch-pad is working but the advance functions do not work!

Comment: Did you try to re-install the driver and see what happens?